# gas exceeds allowance

Tags: solidity, javascript, ropsten, out-of-gas

I'm testing my smart contract on ropsten and I have written an async function that lets me send `TRANSACTION` transactions from `TRANSACTION` different accounts. For some reason when `TRANSACTION > 20` i get caught in the catch statment with a gas exceeds allowance error and i can't figure out why. I have similarly written a function to fund an arbitrary amount of accounts with eth. Litterally all that is done on the smart contract when invoking `instance.methods.addSubmission...` is push a `uint256` into an array in a `mapping(uint256 => uint256[])`

```js
async function multipleTx() {
  let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
  console.log('Issuing Transactions...')
  let totalGasUsed = 0
  const promisesArr = []
  const sendBlockNumber = await web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
  const sendTimeStamp = Date.now()

  for (let i = 0; i < TRANSACTIONS; i++) {
    console.log('account', i, 'is', accounts[i])
    promisesArr.push(
      instance.methods.addSubmissionNoCheck(1, 139).send({
        from: accounts[i],
        gasPrice: 10000000000,
      })
    )
  }
  await Promise.all(promisesArr)
    .then(async (receipts) => {
      let lastBlock = receipts[0].blockNumber
      receipts.forEach((receipt) => {
        totalGasUsed += receipt.gasUsed
        lastBlock =
          receipt.blockNumber > lastBlock ? receipt.blockNumber : lastBlock
      })
      await outputResults(
        sendTimeStamp,
        totalGasUsed,
        sendBlockNumber,
        lastBlock
      )
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log('multipleTX():', error)
    })
}
```

console output:

```js
multipleTX(): Error: gas required exceeds allowance (8000029) or always failing
transaction
    at C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules
\@truffle\hdwallet-provider\node_modules\web3-provider-engine\subproviders\provi
der.js:18:36
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukv
aruteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\web3-providers-http\src\index.js:96:
13)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvar
uteknik\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request-event-ta
rget.ts:44:13)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\ex
amensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:219:8)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvarutekni
k\examensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:345:8)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Diddi\Documents\mjukvaruteknik\exam
ensarbete\tqdt33\node_modules\xhr2-cookies\xml-http-request.ts:311:39)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:228:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1185:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
```

smart contract function

```js
mapping(uint256 => uint256[]) public submissions;

function addSubmissionNoCheck(uint256 key, uint256 timeAtLocation) external {
  submissions[key].push(timeAtLocation);
}
```

### Update:

I have removed the gas limit specification as per my own solution below and instead and overfunded the accounts and it seems to work now. I've ran multiple times doing 20 transactions from 20 different accounts. However i feel like if the problem was insufficent funds in the accounts i should receive the `Insufficient funds for gas * price + value` error.

Comment: can you post the console output please

Comment: @MajdTL sure!:)

Comment: What are you doing in addSubmission? Are you testing in ropsten or a private testnet? (in ropsten case do you have a transaction hash that fails?) The error message says that either a transaction requires more gas than allowed of it reverts.

Comment: @Ismael i updated my post to include the smart contract function. Yes i'm testing on ropsten but i get no transaction hash returned to me since i never get inside the `then` clause. I also manually checked some of the addresses supposedly used in my for loop on etherscan but i find no failed transactions according to etherscan, in fact no new transactions at all so they are not being sent

Comment: That's `addSubmissionNoCheck`, not `addSubmission`! May I speculate that you have a `require` statement in the former?

Comment: @goodvibration I have just changed the name since before but the problem remains the exact same. I have updated the post to reflect the changes. I have two versions of `addSubmission` one of them has a require modifier on it but i don't use it rn for testing purposes

Comment: "For some reason when `TRANSACTION > 20` i get caught in the catch statement" - do you have more than 20 accounts? I suspect not. Even if yes, for good practice, you should use `i < accounts.length` instead of `i < TRANSACTIONS`.

Comment: @goodvibration i have unlocked 100 accounts and also funded them with eth. Therefore i cannot use `accounts.length` in the for loop because then i will issue 100 transactions. I have it so that `TRANSACTION` gets incremented by 5 and so when the test runs i get expected results for 5,10,15 until i reach 20 whereupon i get the error. But even just running it once starting on `TRANSACTION = 20` and ending there i get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seem to have been entirely a problem with Infura. I suspect it is in regard to their rate limits. Nevertheless we have now set up our own ethereum node using geth and are able to isssue as many transactions as we want pretty much problem free!

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have solved my issues by setting a lower gas limit on each of the transactions such that they sum up to a gas limit lower than `8,000,000 GAS`  which is the gas limit of a block. So for instance, with 20 transactions, i set it to `75000`since I saw based on the receipts my tx costs in the worst case my `addSubmission` function costs `69095`. `75000 * 20 < 8,000,000`  and it went through.

### Why did it work? Thoughts

web3 is calculating the potential gas required by taking `gas limit * number of transacting accounts` and if this exceeds block gas limit it fails. Now it does work if in the for loop i use the same account then I can fire off 20 transactions without a problem but since i use multiple accounts for whatever reason web3 first caluclates gas limits as if it was separate accounts but then when the `promise.All` runs it applies the calculated gas such that it's ONE transaction from ONE account and it exceeds the block gas limit and therefore fails. This might be because the walletprovider for the web3 instance uses the same mneumonic? i set it the following way

```js
const walletProvider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, infura.endpoint, 0, 100)
const web3 = new Web3(walletProvider)
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense. If there are more transactions than possible to fit in one block it should create more blocks instead of failing.

Comment: @Ismael I'm not sure what to say. I showed my friend, who'm I'm working with, the error and he saw the `exceeds allowance` and he thought maybe it's calculating `gas limit * number of accounts` and if it exceeds the block gas limit it won't allow me to send the transaction. I thought it did not make sense but we tried and it does work now.  So we don't quite understand why it works. I am quite confused..

Comment: Are you testing against ropsten or rinkeby? Do you have a transaction hash of a failed transaction? A related problem, since you are using infura, is that they limit how many request you can send with a free account.

Comment: @Ismael Yes this is on ropsten. No i don't have a transaction hash since i get caught in the catch statement so i don't get a tx receipt and I also checked the addresses manually on etherscan and there is no recorded transaction when it fails. Lastly, i am no way near the 100,000requests/day limit. i know this because i still can issue transactions just not the way i mentioned in my original post

Comment: The lack of a failed transaction hint the problem is not in the contract but somewhere between your script and the blockchain. Perhaps you exceed some internal limit of node, web3 or infura (perhaps it takes too long to process many transactions). Also 100k req/day is not that much, around 69 req/min.

Comment: @Ismael Indeed, it's not the contract. But i am 100% sure i've not hit the request limit because, like i said, i can still issue requests if i do what i did in my "solution". But i do believe, like you said, i've hit some internal limit within web3 and I believe that the limit hast got to do something with GAS expenditure.

Comment: I still suspect the problem is with infura since in the past I made similar tests to measure performance where I've to send hundreds of transactions using web3.js to a private testnet without any issue.

Comment: @Ismael yeah i think you're right it's something with infura but it cannot be that i have hit my quota of requests because i can still issue requests. Idk if you saw i updated the original post and i funded the accounts with more eth than necessary and it seems to work. So i could remove the "fixes" from my answer and just do that. However, if it was a problem of insufficient funds i should've received a different error :S